# How to create an Excel file extension .xlsx from a dictionary using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dictionary, data-structures

I am new to the library `import openpyxl` using `python` and i went through many posts on stackoverflow to find a good example of the case below that i can learn from.

I have the dictionary below.

## dictionary

```
people = [
    {
        "Name": 'Adam',
        "Age": 28,
        "Country": "US",
    },
    {
        "Name": 'Helena',
        "Age": 18,
        "Country": "France",
    },
    {
        "Name": 'John',
        "Age": 23,
        "Country": "US",
    },
    {
        "Name": 'Remy',
        "Age": 34,
        "Country": "France",
    },
]
```

How can i possibly create an excel file extension `.xlsx` using `openpyxl` speficically based on the data above?

## result expected

[image]

Any help would be much appreciate?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to convert the people list shown above to pandas dataframe and use `to_excel` to write to a file. Code given below. Note that if you don't specify `sheet_name`, it will write to default Sheet1 and if you don't use `index=False`, there will be an index column added in excel sheet column A. Rest is pretty straightforward. Hope this helps.
Note that pandas uses `openpyxl` under the hood to write to excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(people) #Convert people to list
df.to_excel('MyXL.xlsx', sheet_name = 'SheetName', index = False) #Write to myXL
```

**Output Excel**

[image]